# NDKr8b and gnu++0x status

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to use gnu++0x features in my native android code. I'm using the lastest version (r8b, with toolchain 4.6) and while code using std::chrono or std::thread works well using linux gcc 4.6, it seems that these features are not supported in android ndk.

To compile, I use the following flags in the Application.mk file :

```
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x
    APP_STL := gnustl_shared
    APP_GNUSTL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions
```

May I do something wrong ? Is there a link to know the status of the c++0x support in android ndk ?

Thanks a lot !

Regards,

JB

Just a sample code like this :

```
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = 
            std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::milliseconds duration (100);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);

    std::chrono::milliseconds elapsedTime =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
```

With headers,

```
    #include <chrono>
    #include <thread>
```

Using ndk-build, I've got an error message like this :

```
    error: 'chrono' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
    ....
    error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
```

And all about chrono and thread !

Comment: I strongly recommend to run `ndk-build` with `V=1` and you will see the actual `g++` command line that is executed. It will be much easier to find the problem with `std::chrono` and `std::this_thread` namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I succeed in using chrono in the Android NDK. I just added this line to my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++11
```

I also added this line in Application.mk to solve some issues I had using chrono:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Now you have support for c++11 including chrono.

Answer (score 0):

```
<NDK_root_folder>/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html
```

that's all, here you get all the informations and the support that your NDK can give to your C++ code.

Comment: Of course, this page give us what is supported but no word about c++0x.

Comment: I really don't think so, i don't think that the NDK supports such feature, the log of their releases is quite detailed, and there is no trace of this, also such C++ related features are drafts and only recently becomes a standard, you can always ask in the appropriate google groups where you can get a more precise information about this http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk

Comment: In the gnu-libstd++ implementation (<NDK_ROOT>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6), there is the current gnu implementation of c++0x but seems to be underexploited.

Comment: i think that they are working on that, if you consider the samples apps that comes with the NDK you will see that `test-libstdc++` is undocumented , also on the official website for the NDK this sample app is not mentioned at the time that i'm writing this post http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Samples , i think that for an advanced support for the C++ you have to wait at least 1-2 more releases.

Answer (score 0):

have a try:
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
    Define this variable to either 4.4.3 or 4.6 to select version of GCC compiler.
    4.6 is the default